# Утилиты Linux с суффиксом ctl

Tags: linux

Где или как в терминале можно посмотреть их все? Знаю только sysctl, systemctl, hostnamectl, localectl и timedatectl, не уверен что это все.

Comment: `find /usr/ -not -path '/usr/share/*' -type f -name '*ctl'` например так можно посмотреть

Comment: да как обычно: `$ ls /{,usr/}{,s}bin/*ctl`

Comment: `find ${PATH//:/ } -type f -name '*ctl'` либо по переменным окружениям поиск сделать

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, способ с выводом содержимого директорий побыстрее чем find, спасибо, вообще я думал что есть какая-то команда, которая выводит список установленных утилит и ее вывод передать в grep | egrep через пайп, такой вариант вообще был бы идеальным

Comment: есть такая программа. *ls* называется. `$ ls /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin`, или, короче, пользуясь возможностями программы-оболочки: `$ ls /{,usr/}{,s}bin`. если очень хочется ещё одну программу запустить (*grep*, например) — запускайте.

Comment: Забавно со временем конечно, у меня на сереве показывает `ls` **real    0m0.007s**, `find` **real    0m0.008s**

Comment: @PotroNik а вы поди `find` не первый раз на сервере запускаете. Сбросьте кэш (либо перезагрузите сервер для чистоты эксперимента) и протестируйте еще раз `real time`.

Comment: @de_frag, действительно, проверил еще на 3 серверах, максимальное время составило **real    0m0.080s**, при этому у ls время выполнения максимальное **real    0m0.018s**. Но стоит учесть, что find ищет по всем переменным окружениям, не только в /usr/s|bin.

Comment: @PotroNik, ничто не мешает передать программе *ls* ровно тот же список аргументов (содержащих каталоги), что вы передаёте программе *find*: `$ ls ${PATH//:/\/*ctl }` (в моём первом комментарии предложено просматривать не «только /usr/bin и /usr/sbin», но и /bin и /sbin)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а вот это хорошее предложение `ls ${PATH//://*ctl } 2>/dev/null` что бы не видеть ошибки на каталоги, в которых файлы отсутствуют

Comment: Да, кстати, сразу не увидел, что каталоги /bin, /sbin участвуют. В любом случае правильнее тот вариант с ls, который все переменные окружения смотрит.

Comment: @PotroNik, 1. равно как и «заворачивание» ошибок от программы *find* — в случае отсутствия каталога, упомянутого в переменной PATH. 2. нет, не «правильнее», а всего лишь «аналогично вашему»: в переменной PATH у пользователя совсем не обязательно присутствие каталогов /sbin и /usr/sbin.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если у него отсутствует в переменном окружении каталог то и приложение он не запустит из него без указания полного пути. *find* ругается если каталог полностью отсутствует, *ls* дополнительно еще когда в каталоге нет файлов подходящих под условие выборки по маске.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите найти вообще все `*ctl*` во всех репах, на Debian есть замечательная утилита `apt-file`

Сначала ставим ее и обновляем ее базу:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Затем ищем:

```
apt-file search ctl | grep bin | grep -v "/usr/share/"
```

У меня выдало 373 файлов. Там же показывается и название пакета

```
...
ekeyd: /usr/sbin/ekeydctl
emboss: /usr/bin/jembossctl
encfs: /usr/bin/encfsctl
...
```

Comment: Для поиска пакета, по его имени или содержимому, вместо `apt-file`, можно воспользоваться [страницей](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) на сайте Debian. На Ubuntu есть аналогичная.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, спасибо за ссылку. Похоже на поиск через `apt search`. Но `apt-file` решает больше задач. Недавно искал утилиту для проверки подписи dkim. Через поиск по пакетам выдается десяток пакетов, но не во всех есть эта утилита (а название ее я и не знаю). `apt-file search dkim | grep bin` просто шикарно справилась с этой задачей.

Comment: Интересно в вопросе не слова про конкретный дистр не было :) как быть ползователям других сборок?

Comment: @Hellseher, подсмотреть название на дебине, поискать в своем. Собственно я так для Alpine образа искал.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ locate *ctl | grep bin
/bin/journalctl
/bin/keyctl
/bin/loginctl
/bin/networkctl
/bin/systemctl
/bin/wdctl
/sbin/initctl
/sbin/mntctl
/sbin/pccardctl
/sbin/sysctl
/sbin/zramctl
/usr/bin/bluetoothctl
/usr/bin/bootctl
/usr/bin/busctl
/usr/bin/hostnamectl
/usr/bin/localectl
/usr/bin/obexctl
/usr/bin/pactl
/usr/bin/timedatectl
/usr/bin/udisksctl
/usr/sbin/alsactl
/usr/sbin/cupsctl
/usr/sbin/rtkitctl
/usr/sbin/smartctl
```